# Por que mi vector no se guarda correctamente en el archivo de texto?

Tags: c

El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero guardar el contenido en un archivo de texto, no lo hace, simplemente me guarda la basura de las variables... a continuacion les dejo el codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<windows.h>
struct cedula{
   int id[4],cuenta[4];
};
struct saldos{
float saldoAnterior;
};
struct banco{
cedula s;
saldos f;
};
int leer();
void llenaClientes(banco);
FILE * abrirArchivo();
void cedulaA(banco);
int main(){
int opc;
banco clientes;
do{
    printf("\nOpcion: ");
    opc=leer();
    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            llenaClientes(clientes);                
        break;  
    }   
}while(opc!=0);

}
int leer(){
int n;
scanf("%i",&n);
return n;
}


void llenaClientes(banco l){
    FILE *apuB;
    cedulaA(l);
    printf("\nIngrese el saldo del cliente: ");
    scanf("%f",&l.f.saldoAnterior);
    apuB=abrirArchivo();

    if(apuB==NULL){
        printf("\nNo se pudo abrir el archivo...");
    }else{
        fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|%i\n",l.s.id,l.s.cuenta,l.f.saldoAnterior);
        fclose(apuB);
    }
}

FILE * abrirArchivo(){
    FILE *apufile=fopen("Banamex.txt","a+");
    return apufile;
}

void cedulaA(banco l){
    printf("\n>>>Asignando cedula y numero de cuenta<<<");
    int numero;
    int hora=time(NULL);
    srand(hora);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        l.s.id[i]=rand()%9; 
        l.s.cuenta[i]=rand()%9;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en el código.
Imagino que estas usando un compilador de C bajo Windows.
Debo decirte que

1. (es una observación) La librería **windows.h** no es necesaria para lo que estas haciendo.
2. (es una observación) La librería **stdlib.h** es necesaria para lo del srand (según el C estandar hay que usarla).
3. La firma de los métodos no esta bien escrita. Esta mal usar:

   void llenaClientes(banco);

Deberías usar:

```
void llenaClientes(struct banco);
```

Esa es la forma estándar, el tipo es **struct banco** no solo **banco**. Me haz de decir ¿eso que importancia tiene? Bueno el código que pusiste al no ser estándar no compilará con otro compilador que no sea el tuyo (tuve que moverlo por que conmigo simplemente no compilaba). Esto es lo que se conoce como perdida de portabilidad.

4. (Este es un problema critico) Al escribir al archivo estas haciendo:

   fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|%i\n",l.s.id,l.s.cuenta,l.f.saldoAnterior);

Pero **l.s.id** es un arreglo lo mismo que **l.s.cuenta** por lo que deberías escribir cada uno de los 4 enteros del arreglo que representa el id y cada uno de los 4 enteros que representa la cuenta. El valor del saldoAnterior debe imprimirse usando %f preferentemente indicando los decimales que vas a manejar.

```
fprintf(apuB,"%i%i%i%i|%i%i%i%i|%f\n"
                        ,l.s.id[0]
                        ,l.s.id[1]
                        ,l.s.id[2]
                        ,l.s.id[3]
                        ,l.s.cuenta[0]
                        ,l.s.cuenta[1]
                        ,l.s.cuenta[2]
                        ,l.s.cuenta[3]
                        ,l.f.saldoAnterior);
```

5. (Este también es un problema critico). Estas pasando por valor las variables de tipo **struct banco** por lo que al salir del método donde se pasa se pierde el valor que tenían. Como nos comenta @efqerion es necesario usar indirección y apuntadores (punteros) al menos debe usarse indirección en la funación cedulaA() pues ella inicializa los valores de la cuenta y el id.

Mi propuesta con lo comentado es:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct cedula{
   int id[4];
   int cuenta[4];
};

struct saldos{
   float saldoAnterior;
};

struct banco{
   struct cedula s;
   struct saldos f;
};

int leer();
void llenaClientes(struct banco);

FILE * abrirArchivo();

void cedulaA(struct banco * );

int leer(){
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    return n;
}



int main(){
    int opc;
    struct banco clientes;

    do{
        printf("\nOpcion: ");
        opc=leer();
        switch(opc){
                case 1:
                    llenaClientes(clientes);                
                break;  
            }   
    }while(opc!=0);

}




void llenaClientes(struct banco l){
    FILE *apuB;
    // piensa esta invocación como una analogía al uso del & en
    // el scanf que haz puesto abajo.
    cedulaA(&l);

    printf("\nIngrese el saldo del cliente: ");
    scanf("%f",&l.f.saldoAnterior);
    apuB=abrirArchivo();

    if(apuB==NULL){
        printf("\nNo se pudo abrir el archivo...");
    }else{
        fprintf(apuB,"%i%i%i%i|%i%i%i%i|%f\n"
            ,l.s.id[0]
            ,l.s.id[1]
            ,l.s.id[2]
            ,l.s.id[3]
            ,l.s.cuenta[0]
            ,l.s.cuenta[1]
            ,l.s.cuenta[2]
            ,l.s.cuenta[3]
            ,l.f.saldoAnterior);
        fclose(apuB);
    }
}

FILE * abrirArchivo(){
    FILE * apufile=fopen("Banamex.txt","a+");
    return apufile;
}

void cedulaA(struct banco * l){
    printf("\n>>>Asignando cedula y numero de cuenta<<<");
    int numero;
    int hora=time(NULL);
    srand(hora);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        l->s.id[i]=rand()%9; 
        l->s.cuenta[i]=rand()%9;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Muy buena solución.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás pasando `banco` por valor:

```
void llenaClientes(banco l){
//                       ^ AQUI
  FILE *apuB;
  cedulaA(l);
//        ^ y aqui
```

Al pasar una variable (estructura o tipo nativo) por valor se hace una copia de la misma, la cual será totalmente independiente de la variable original.

Con los punteros pasa algo similar. Los punteros son copias independientes (puedes hacer un malloc en uno y el otro no se enterará), lo que sucede en este caso es que si dos o más punteros apuntan (valga la redundancia) a la misma dirección de memoria, los cambios realizados en la misma sí que serán compartidos.

La solución pasa por usar punteros:

```
void llenaClientes(banco*);
void cedulaA(banco*);

int main(){
  banco clientes;
  // ...
  llenaClientes(&clientes);
  // ...
}

void llenaClientes(banco *l){
  cedulaA(l);
  // ...
  scanf("%f",&l->f.saldoAnterior);
  // ...
  fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|%i\n",l->s.id,l->s.cuenta,l->f.saldoAnterior);
  // ...
}

void cedulaA(banco *l){
  // ...
  l->s.id[i]=rand()%9;
  l->s.cuenta[i]=rand()%9;
  // ...
}
```

Por otro lado, date cuenta de que tanto `id` como `cuenta` son arrays, luego si para rellenar la estructura usas un índice:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  l->s.id[i]=rand()%9;
  l->s.cuenta[i]=rand()%9;
}
```

Necesitarás un índice también para imprimir los valores:

```
fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|%i\n",l->s.id,l->s.cuenta,l->f.saldoAnterior);
//                             ^^      ^^^^^^
//                             Falta el indice
```

Quizás algo así:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|",l->s.id[i],l->s.cuenta[i]);
}
fprintf(apuB,"%i\n",l->f.saldoAnterior);
```

Aunque quizás tiene más sentido, en vez de tener dos arrays iguales, gestionar todo con un único array. Dado que se sobreentiende que a cada identificador le va a corresponder un número de cuenta:

```
struct cedula{
  int id;
  int cuenta;
};
struct saldos{
  float saldoAnterior;
};
struct banco{
  cedula s[4];
  saldos f;
};

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  l->s[i].id=rand()%9;
  l->s[i].cuenta=rand()%9;
}

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|",l->s[i].id,l->s[i].cuenta);
}
fprintf(apuB,"%i\n",l->f.saldoAnterior);
```

Ya que te permitiría, por ejemplo, usar aritmética de punteros:

```
cedula* ptr = l->s;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++, ptr++){
  ptr->id=rand()%9;
  ptr->cuenta=rand()%9;
}

cedula* ptr = l->s;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++, ptr++)
  fprintf(apuB,"%i|%i|",ptr->id,ptr->cuenta);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, fue muy útil :)